# What do we know about functions $f(x)$ such that $f''(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

While I do know the case for $f(x)=f'(x)$ as that is simply $f(x)=ae^x$, I am wondering if there is any known restrictions to solutions to $f(x)=f''(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Solutions are $f(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}$

Comment: Read about second order linear differential equation: homogenous solution

Comment: e.g., on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are always of the form $a e^x + b e^{-x}$.

This can be demonstrated as follows:

$f(x) - f''(x) = 0$ is equivalent to $f(x) + f'(x) - f'(x) - f''(x) = 0$, is equivalent to $g(x) - g'(x) = 0$ where $g(x)$ is defined to be $f(x) + f'(x)$. But then we know that $g(x) = a e^x$. Then $f(x) + f'(x) = a e^x$. It can thus be shown that $f(x) = \frac{a}{2} e^x + b e^{-x}$. But since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants, we can just replace $\frac{a}{2}$ with $a$.

Comment: Can you explain the step that leads to $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}e^x+be^{-x}$?

Comment: @AjaxDirtWormton \begin{align} f' + f &= ae^{x} \\ \implies e^{x}f' + e^{x}f &= a e^{2x} \\ \implies (e^{x} f)' &= ae^{2x} \\ \implies e^{x} f &= \int ae^{2x} dx = \frac{ae^{2x}}{2} + b \\ \implies f &= \frac{ae^{x}}{2} + be^{-x} \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=f''(x)$$
Let $f(x)=e^x \,z(x)$ which make
$$z''(x)+2z'(x)=0$$ Reduction of order
$$p'(x)+2p(x)=0 \implies p(x)=c_1 e^{-2x}\implies z'(x)=c_1 e^{-2x}\implies z(x)=-\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{-2 x}+c_2$$

Go back to $f(x)$ and replace the constants.

Answer (score 0):

Given,

$$f''(x)=f(x)$$

Multiply with $f'(x)$ on both sides

$$f''(x)\cdot f'(x)=f(x)\cdot f'(x)$$

Now integrating on both sides,

$$\frac{{f'(x)}^2}{2}=\frac{{f(x)}^2}{2} +c$$ (where c is intgration constant)

i.e,
$$f'(x)=\sqrt{(f(x))^2+c}$$

So,

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{(f(x))^2+c}}dy = \int dx$$

$$\Rightarrow\ln \left|f(x)+\sqrt{(f(x))^2+c}\right| = x+\mathcal{D}$$, (where D is integrating constant)

Let $y=f(x)$ ,

$$\rightarrow y+\sqrt{y^2+c}=C_oe^{\pm x}$$  (let $ln\mathcal{D}=C_o$)

Squaring on both sides gives,

$$\rightarrow y^2+c=\left(C_oe^{\pm x}-y\right)^2$$

$$\rightarrow c=C_o^2e^{\pm2x}-2C_2e^{\pm x}y$$

So,

$${y=Ce^{\pm x}+C'e^{\mp x}}$$

(Where $C$ and $ C'$ are constants)